# Parsing a FormattedDate on a destinationView

Tags: ios, json

I'm parsing some information to my app using JSON. I'm able to show the formattedDate on my Main View Controller but when I want to do it on my destinationView page (UpcomingReleaseViewController), I get a "null" string. This is what I have so far:

**UpcomingRelease.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *release_date;

- (NSString *) formattedDate;
```

**UpcomingRelease.m**

```
- (NSString *) formattedDate {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:self.release_date];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EE MMM,dd"];
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:tempDate];

}
```

**UpcomingReleaseViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UpcomingRelease *singleRelease;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *release_date;
```

**UpcomingReleaseViewController.m**

```
@synthesize singleRelease = _singleRelease;
@synthesize release_date = _release_date;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.release_date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _singleRelease.formattedDate];
}
```

**JSON**

```
release_date: "2013-09-28T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Thanks.

Comment: So, what does self.release_date look like??

Comment: And how does _singleRelease get set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UpcomingRelease.m you need to parse the date's 'T' and 'Z' as literal characters and account for the fractional seconds:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
```